# 05 Jeep Liberty V6 - Battery died, computer reset, running extremely rough. Only code is P0137, and new o2 sensor reads 0v

Tags: jeep, o2-sensor, liberty

Title basically sums it up, I have an 05 Liberty with the V6. Battery died over the big chill last week because I left a dash cam plugged in for a few days. Once I got the car running, it was running extremely rough. It was consistent though. I almost wondered if I was down a few cylinders.

Scanned codes and the only one present was p0137 Bank 1 downstream o2 low voltage. Granted- the computer was reset and it had only been driven about 6 miles in all, but it did have 2-3 full heat cycles. Previously I had a possible vacuum leak CEL that would usually show up after about a hundred miles of driving so I am guessing that one just hasn't triggered yet. No other codes before or currently.

Real time data shows 0 volts on that o2 sensor. The sensor is seized real tight onto the exhaust so I just plugged a new sensor in and let it hang to see if I could get a voltage reading, but it was still 0 volts.

I am guessing that the harness has a short somewhere, I haven't gotten that far. However, for how rough the car is running, I am surprised (and skeptical) it could be caused by the downstream sensor. But I don't have any other codes, other than the real time data showed a closed loop fault for a bit, but that.s not a code just an observation. I feel like this is a symptom of a bigger issue and am looking for any common failures I should check on since I don't have any other codes to check into. Or, if I am wrong and the downstream sensor can absolutely cause a very rough engine and severe lack of power, let me know.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!